# Distribute evenly such that object spacing to page margins = spacing between objects

Tags: inkscape, alignment

How do I distribute objects evenly horizontally in Inkscape, such that the spacing between the objects equals that of the left (right) object to the left (right) edge of the page?

<sup>Similar to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/137072/56403); cf. [this comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137072/inkscape-how-to-evenly-space-objects/137074?noredirect=1#comment238372_137074)</sup>

Comment: Most distribution doesn't "see" any page as a thing to measure. Customarily one places temporary objects which align with page edges, then distributes, then removes the two outer objects. At least that's what needs to be done in Illustrator.. I'm not an Inkscape user.

Comment: @Scott - its more or less the same in Inkscape.

Comment: @Scott That's interesting neither Illustrator nor Inkscape have a built-in feature to do that without using helper objects.

Comment: @Geremia - The problem is if the objects to be distributed overlap a page/object, then the distribute function isn't gong to work if you try to distribute them with reference to that. It would just mess up. It needs to be applied on distinct objects which don't overlap, so that it can distribute the objects relative to each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a couple of helper objects aligned to the edge of the rectangle (or page) by using snapping, then do the distribute, then delete the helper objects.

[image]